# Get value with multiple elements with common name

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with `map()`. I try get all variables from my form but I can't have multiple types of element (input, select, textaera)

```
<input type="text" name="ctrl[]" />
<select name="ctrl[]" />
<textarea  name="ctrl[]" />
```

```js
var values = $("select[name='ctrl\\[\\]']").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

This works fine with `input` but not for select and textaera. Can you help me?

Comment: remove select and try `var values = $("[name='ctrl\\[\\]']")
.map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();`

Comment: No need to escape the `[]` when used inside quotes of attribute value

Comment: You could also give all of the inputs you WANT to .map... a class name, and just map to that class: `$(".mapthis").map(...`

Comment: Not sure what specific problem is. The basics work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/fj74n9aw/

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the select from the selector:

```
var values = $("[name='ctrl[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Above code will select all type of the input which will have the name `ctrl[]`.

`$("select[name='ctrl\\[\\]']")` is bounding you to select only select box values with the name `ctrl[]`.

```js
var values = $("[name='ctrl[]']").map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get();

console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="ctrl[]" value="input_value" /><br>
<select name="ctrl[]">
  <option value="selectd_value">option 1</option>
</select><br>
<textarea name="ctrl[]">textarea_value</textarea>
```